# How much do the PF XL motors help speed in the 4x4 crawler?

Tags: power-functions

I'm wanting an answer if anyone has swapped the PF L motors in the 4x4 crawler to PF XL motors and if this increases the speed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up the Bucket Wheel Excavator by adding an additional XL motor. It is not just about changing the motor, it is also about changing the gear ratios. There is a very good instructional video here: https://youtu.be/aLQh_VWzy9Y